# Colors not varying - python graphics

Tags: python

I'm trying to reproduce something to this effect.

[image]

```
import graphics
from graphics import color_rgb
import random
window= graphics.GraphWin("x", 600, 400)
stripes = input("How many stripes should be on the flag")
stripes = int(stripes)
count = 0
count = int(count)
P1=graphics.Point(0,0) #left corner - anchor point
for x in range(stripes): #loop for number of stripes
    col= random.randint(1,255)
    stepdim = 400/stripes #size of divisions
    stepdim = int(stepdim)
    shrink = count*stepdim
    shrink = int(shrink)
    stepdim = stepdim*10 #enlarge to an increment below the last
    stepdim = stepdim-shrink
    stepdim = int(stepdim)
    P2=graphics.Point(600,stepdim) #bottom right corner - ever shrinking
    outsiderec=graphics.Rectangle(P1,P2) #
    outsiderec.setFill(color_rgb(100, col, 0))
    outsiderec.draw(window)
    count= count + 1
    count= int(count)
window.getMouse()
window.close()
```

I'm instead receiving one flat color. 
[image]
I assume the problem is in my rand(int). I don't really know the ins and outs of it. Is it not running more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code as base I have tried to reproduce the expected result.

```
import graphics
from graphics import color_rgb
import random

window= graphics.GraphWin("x", 600, 400)
stripes = input("How many stripes should be on the flag")
stripes = int(stripes)
#count = 0
#count = int(count)
#P1=graphics.Point(0,0) #left corner - anchor point
stepdim = 400/stripes #size of divisions
for x in range(stripes): #loop for number of stripes
    #col= random.randint(1,255)
    #stepdim = int(stepdim)
    #shrink = count*stepdim
    #shrink = int(shrink)
    #stepdim = stepdim*10 #enlarge to an increment below the last
    #stepdim = stepdim-shrink
    #stepdim = int(stepdim)
    #P2=graphics.Point(600,stepdim) #bottom right corner - ever shrinking
    P1=graphics.Point(0, stepdim * x) #left corner - anchor point
    P2=graphics.Point(600,stepdim * (x + 1)) #bottom right corner - ever shrinking
    outsiderec=graphics.Rectangle(P1,P2)
    #outsiderec.setFill(color_rgb(100, col, 0))
    red = random.randint(1, 255)
    green = random.randint(1, 255)
    blue = random.randint(1, 255)
    outsiderec.setFill(color_rgb(red, green, blue))
    outsiderec.draw(window)
    #count= count + 1
    #count= int(count)
window.getMouse()
window.close()
```

I have:

- commented out all those statement that aren't needed
- moved `stepdim = 400/stripes` from inside the loop to outside because you don't need to compute the same value for every loop
- moved the `P1=graphics.Point(0,0)` inside the loop with a slight modification just to point to the top left corner of the stripe
- modified the `P2=graphics.Point(600,stepdim)` to point to the bottom right corner of the stripe
- added a random calculation for the three color components `red = random.randint(1, 255)`, `green = random.randint(1, 255)`, and `blue = random.randint(1, 255)`

Observations:

I have changed a little bit the way the stripes are drawn. Instead of drawing a shrunk version for every loop, the modified version just draws a fixed size stripe in consecutive positions.